# Issues with ggplot2 geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to have ggplot2 plot percentage instead of frequency on the y axis but it just doesn't work! I have added `scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())` to my plot but it still displays frequencies. Here's my code:

```
ggplot(items) + geom_bar( aes(x = type, fill = category), position = "dodge") + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

Here is a sample of my dataset

```
head(items)

       item   type category
[1]    PA100   1    A
[2]    PB101   2    A
[3]    UR360   2    A
[4]    PX977   3    B
[5]    GA008   3    B
[6]    GR446   3    A
```

What I want to do is for each category A and B I want to plot the percentage of type 1, type 2, and type 3 it has; hence my code. But no matter what it keeps plotting the frequencies of type 1, 2, and 3 in each of the categories instead of the percentages :|

Comment: What is your y? Is it already in percentage? It would be great if you can add reproducible data.

Comment: @jazzurro errr i don't have my own y i have a categorical variable in the x axis and i want to plot its percentage on the y axis. let me add some more details to my question

Comment: @user20650 thanks the scaling of the y axis has changed but the plots remain the same :((

Comment: @user20650 no I mean the plots still are at the level of the frequencies not categories. I know because I calculated the percentage of each type within each category and thats not what the plots are showing. besides the scaling in the y axis show only 0% to 25% I have no idea whats going on

Comment: See my answer below. Is this what you want?

Comment: @rnso yes yes yessss thats what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
items = structure(list(item = structure(c(3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("GA008", 
"GR446", "PA100", "PB101", "PX977", "UR360"), class = "factor"), 
    type = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), category = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("item", 
"type", "category"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

items
   item type category
1 PA100    1        A
2 PB101    2        A
3 UR360    2        A
4 PX977    3        B
5 GA008    3        B
6 GR446    3        A

tt = with(items, table(type, category))
tt
    category
type A B
   1 1 0
   2 2 0
   3 1 2

dd = data.frame(prop.table(tt, 2))
dd
  type category Freq
1    1        A 0.25
2    2        A 0.50
3    3        A 0.25
4    1        B 0.00
5    2        B 0.00
6    3        B 1.00

ggplot(dd)+geom_bar(aes(x=type, y=Freq, fill=category), stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

[image]